# Propositional Logic - Resolution Strategies

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need help understanding these resolution strategies.

> 1) Set of support 
>   2) Linear input

Let's assume $\mathcal{S} = \{ C_1, ... ,C_n\}$ is our set of clauses.

and we want to derive / prove the conclusion clause $G$ (via resolution).

So we will add the negate of the conclusion clause $\lnot G$ to our clauses.

> **Question 1:**
>
> How does the **Set of support** strategy work?
>   How does the **Linear input** strategy work?
>
> **Question 2:**
>
> What are the pros and cons of each strategy? 
>   Why would u prefer to choose SoS and why would you prefer to chose Linear input?

Would really appreciate help, my exam is tomorrow, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution Strategies:

**Set of support:**

The set of support partitions all clauses into two sets, the set of support and auxiliary set.

We initialize the auxiliary set to be the set S (our starting set of clauses).
We initialize the set of support to be the negated conclusion ~G.

Our resolution will always use at least 1 clause from the set of support.
All clauses derived by such action will be added to the set of support.

+This strategy is *complete*.

**Linear**

Linear derivation of $G$ from $S$ is a finite sequence of clauses $R_0,...R_k=G$ such that $R_0\in S$ and each $R_i$ with $1\le i \le k$ is a resolvent of $R_{i-1}$ and a clause $G_i\in S \cup \{R_0,...,R_{i-2}\}$

+This strategy  is *complete*.

**Input**

At least one of the two parent clauses is in $S$.

+Reduces the size of the search space.
+Easy to implement and is efficient.
-Is ONLY *complete* for *Horn clauses*.

**Linear input**

Apply both liner and input strategy together.

+Efficient
-This is *sound* but not *complete*.
-Only *complete* for *Horn clauses*.

---

So basically we will use the set of support strategy if $S$ has *non-horn clauses*. Otherwise we can use the linear input strategy which is more efficient.